# PL/SQL Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION und5.ejer3 does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlprocedure, mysql-procedimiento

Realizar un **procedimiento** que, dado un número de empleado, nos muestre el apellido y su salario. Si no encuentra el empleado, me dará un mensaje de error de ‘Empleado no encontrado’.

```
delimiter //
    drop procedure if exists ejer3;//
    create procedure ejer3 (in Vemp int, out Vapellido varchar(10),
    out Vsalario int, out mensaje varchar(50))
        begin
            
            select APELLIDO, SALARIO
            into Vapellido, Vsalario
            FROM EMPLE
            where EMP_NO=Vemp;
            
            if Vempe!=EMP_NO then
            set mensaje='Empleado no encontrado';
        end;
//

call ejer3(7499,@res1,@res2, @res3)
select ejer3(@res1,@res2, @res3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Tu problema*** es que ***tu código es un procedimiento*** y ***no una función*** por lo que a ***los procedimientos se le llama con CALL*** y a ***las funciones con SELECT***.

***Lo que he hecho básicamente es quitar :***

```
select ejer3(@res1,@res2, @res3)
```

Ya que es eso lo que te esta dando el problema ya que no es una función es un procedimiento.

```
delimiter //
    drop procedure if exists ejer3;//
    create procedure ejer3 (in Vemp int, out Vapellido varchar(10),
    out Vsalario int, out mensaje varchar(50))
        begin
            
            select APELLIDO, SALARIO
            into Vapellido, Vsalario
            FROM EMPLE
            where EMP_NO=Vemp;
            
            if Vempe!=EMP_NO then
            set mensaje='Empleado no encontrado';
        end;
//
```

***Lo llamo con :***

```
call ejer3(7499,@res1,@res2, @res3);
```

Y con eso se soluciona.